# AngularJS UI-Router parent state reloaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, parent-child, reload

I'm trying to create some kind of **inbox app** with messages list on the left, and the detail of the selected message on the right, using UI-Router to do this.

I've a **parent state** that resolves the messages list from database, and a **child state** that resolves the selected message from database (id in parameter).

Problem is : when navigating between messages (child state, juste the id parameter changing), the parent state is also reloaded (view, controller... and the messages list). I don't want it, and I don't understand why it happens.

**Navigation - first solution tried (parent reloaded)**

```
<a ui-sref="app.messengers.show({id: row.id})"></a>
```

**Navigation - second solution tried (parent reloaded)**

```
// Solution 2.1
$state.go('app.messengers.show', {id: id});
// Solution 2.2
$state.transitionTo('app.messengers.show', {id: id});
```

Tried also to add the parameter "reload: false" in both solutions (ui-sref-opts for first solution, in third parameter for the second) : parent reloaded.

**UI-Router**

```
        .state('app.messengers', { // parent state
            abstract: true,            
            url: '/messenger',
            templateUrl: 'app/messengers/list.html',
            controller: 'MessengersController',
            resolve: {
                load: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        'app/messengers/messengerService.js',
                        'app/messengers/messengersController.js'
                    ]);
                }],
                messages: ['load', 'MessengerService', function (load, MessengerService) {
                    return MessengerService.list();
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('app.messengers.show', { // child state
            url: '/:id',
            templateUrl: 'app/messengers/detail.html',
            controller: 'MessengerDetailController',
            params: {
                id: null
            },
            resolve: {
                load1: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        'app/messengers/messengerDetailController.js'
                    ]);
                }],
                message: ['load', '$stateParams', 'MessengerService', function (load, $stateParams, MessengerService) {
                    var regexp = new RegExp('^\\d+$');
                    return (regexp.test($stateParams.id)) ? MessengerService.get($stateParams.id) : null;
                }]
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god...

I forgot that I was doing some checks in the $stateChangeStart (Authentication purpose)... and if everything's ok :

```
$state.go(next.name, params, {reload: true});
```

I've changed the reload parameter to next.name.
It works.

Sorry for that miss...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$state.go('^. show', {id: id});
```

The `^` means parent state.